# How to assign properties of a component inside an MC loaded from a Library?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flash-cs5

I have a Library item: `MovieClip` with a single `ComboBox` component inside. The item has a Class assigned to it, `myMC`.

What I want to achieve is that a call from the main movie like `var mmc:myMC = new myMC( stage);` would:

1. initialize the `ComboBox` instance's values;
2. place the myMC instance on stage (or inside another MC).

So inside the myMC Constructor I wrote smth like:

```
public function myMc( theStage:flash.display.Stage) {
    if( stage == null) this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    theStage.addChild( this);
}

public function init( e:Event = null) {
    var Data:Array= new Array(
        {'label1' : 'item1'},
        {'label2' : 'item2'},
        {'label3' : 'item3'}
    );
    cbox.dataProvider = new DataProvider( Data);
}
```

`cbox` is the name of ComboBox instance within myMC.

What happens is that the ComboBox doesn't have any values assigned. This is a simplified example of my problem, whereas the actual case involves more UI components — all of them miss their values.

Debugger show the component objects of correct type, with the values - but they miss from the stage objects shown!

Please explain, what am I doing wrong - and why does the instance on stage is somehow different from the AS instantiated Object?

Comment: "myMC" is not an optimal class name, nor is passing Stage to a constructor.  You should implement better coding conventions and object oriented standards.

Comment: "myMC" is just for the example. I use packages and a reasonable tree structure for my classes. What can be the better approach to instantiating my component within one or another parent container?

Comment: Where You like to assign property ? Main aplication to loaded SWF , or loaded swf itself ?

Comment: Its not a loaded external swf — single fla and its library of symbols + a bunch of .as classes.

Comment: Seems it was my faulty types definition. Now have a working example of this isolated case. See my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems that it was my mistake: wrong types and messy code.

Here's an example that works afterall. So, maybe its not the best practice to put an object onstage by its own constructor, however this works. The [working example sources](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/libraryAddExample.zip).

Main document has a class DocTest:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import libItem;
    public class DocTest extends Sprite {
        public function DocTest() {
            var instance:libItem = new libItem( this);
        }
    }
}
```

And the library item has a ComboBox and a text field inside, and the following Class code attached:

```
    package  {
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class libItem extends Sprite{

        public function libItem( theParent:flash.display.Sprite) {
            if( stage == null) this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            else init();
            theParent.addChild( this);
        }

        public function init( e:Event = null) {
            var Data:Array= new Array(
                {label:'label1', data: 'item1'},
                {label:'label2', data: 'item2'},
                {label:'label3', data: 'item3'}
            );
            cbox.dataProvider = new DataProvider( Data);
            x = 200;
            y = 100;
            myText.text = 'Woo-hoo!';
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone. Sorry for the studid question.